# JAX-WS Client for perl webservice

Tags: java, perl, webservice-client

I am planning to work on creating a perl webservice[using XML::Compile::SOAP] and want to know if I could create a java client for it using JAX-WS 2.1

[EDIT]: Is there no other way to consume a wsdl without doing the wsdl to java conversion??

Thanks,
Dhawal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a standard SOAP that you can get a standard WSDL from, then using wsimport included with JDK 1.6 should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start by defining the service with a WSDL.  You can then build both the perl server and Java client against that WSDL.  In Eclipse, build both in Java is fairly easy.  A straight forward tutorial on building the client is [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Creating_a_Java_Web_Service_Client). Server tutorial is [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Creating_a_Top-Down_Java_Web_Service_Skeleton_from_a_WSDL_Document).